# How does Ubuntu know what programs exist and can be installed?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, apt-get

I typed the following in a terminal

```
$ musique
The program 'musique' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install musique
```

So Ubuntu knows that "musique" is a program, although it's currently not installed on the machine. However, if I type

```
$ musiquez
No command 'musiquez' found, did you mean:
 Command 'musique' from package 'musique' (universe)
```

it knows that there is no such program called "musiquez".

My question is, how does Ubuntu know this? Where is this information stored about what applications can be installed on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This feature is provided by the [command-not-found](http://packages.ubuntu.com/command-not-found)( Its function is to suggest alternatives and corrections in case of mistyping etc. )  package. Ubuntu installs it by default.

**how does it work?**

The way it works is through the `command_not_found_handle()` function in bash. bash provides a hook which is basically a function that is invoked when a command is not found.

---

If you are more curious, open the `/usr/lib/command-not-found` file and take a look at the script. 
It works using the python module CommandNotFound.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A pair of packages, `command-not-found` and `command-not-found-data`, are what makes this feature work.

`command-not-found` is simply a handler for the `command_not_found_handle()` bash function; it searches through the data about the mapping between commands and packages provided by `command-not-found-data`.

Comment: I would assume that `command-not-found` then checks through the local cache of the repositories that is made every time a user runs `sudo apt-get update`.