# Package name suggestion in fedora

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, package-management, yum

In Ubuntu when an app is not installed and in Terminal you type for example `gvim` it says that this app is contained in package `vim-gnome` and try installing that but in fedora that doesn't happen with yum and it just says `command not found`.

My question is:
is there any way to add this feature or something similar to fedora?  and if not how should I install an app that I don't know it's package name.

Comment: Related: [How does Ubuntu know what programs exist and can be installed?](http://superuser.com/questions/618609/how-does-ubuntu-know-what-programs-exist-and-can-be-installed)

Answer (score 1):

Install the package [PackageKitCommandNotFound](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/PackageKitCommandNotFound).

For install, use:

```
yum install PackageKit-command-not-found
```

Comment: It is installed but doesn't work. when I enter `gdeit` it says `Similar command is: 'gedit'` but when I enter gvim it prints only `bash: gvim: command not found...`

Comment: @Farzam: Unfortunately it was the only package I found for that.